# How to compare two arrays in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, equals, kotlin

Given some arrays in Kotlin

```kotlin
let a = arrayOf("first", "second")
val b = arrayOf("first", "second")
val c = arrayOf("1st", "2nd")
```

Are there built-in functions to the Kotlin std-lib that tests two arrays for (value) equality for each element?

Thus resulting in:

```kotlin
a.equals(b) // true
a.equals(c) // false
```

`equals()` is actually returning `false` in both cases, but maybe there are built-in functions to Kotlin that one could use?

There is the static function `java.utils.Arrays.deepEquals(a.toTypedArray(), b.toTypedArray())` but I would rather prefer an instance method as it would work better with optionals.

Comment: That's probably a case for extension functions.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.1 you can use [`contentEquals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/content-equals.html) and [`contentDeepEquals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/content-deep-equals.html) to compare two arrays for *structural* equality. e.g.:

```
a contentEquals b // true
b contentEquals c // false
```

In Kotlin 1.0 there are no "built-in functions to the Kotlin std-lib that tests two arrays for (value) equality for each element."

"Arrays are always compared using `equals()`, as all other objects" ([Feedback Request: Limitations on Data Classes | Kotlin Blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/feedback-request-limitations-on-data-classes/)).

So `a.equals(b)` will only return `true` if `a` and `b` reference the same array.

You can, however, create your own "optionals"-friendly methods using [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions). e.g.:

```kotlin
fun Array<*>.equalsArray(other: Array<*>) = Arrays.equals(this, other)
fun Array<*>.deepEqualsArray(other: Array<*>) = Arrays.deepEquals(this, other)
```

P.S. The comments on [Feedback Request: Limitations on Data Classes | Kotlin Blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/feedback-request-limitations-on-data-classes/) are worth a read as well, specifically [comment 39364](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/feedback-request-limitations-on-data-classes/#comment-39364).

Comment: Thank god. `Arrays.equals` was too confusing.

Answer (score 25):

Kotlin 1.1 introduced extensions for comparing arrays by content:
[contentEquals](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/content-equals.html) and [contentDeepEquals](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/content-deep-equals.html).

These extensions are *infix*, so you can use them the following way:

```
val areEqual = arr1 contentEquals arr2
```

Answer (score 19):

And if you want to compare contents of two `Collections` **ignoring the order** you can add this simple extension:

```
infix fun <T> Collection<T>.sameContentWith(collection: Collection<T>?)
    = collection?.let { this.size == it.size && this.containsAll(it) }
```

...and use it like this:

```
a = mutableListOf<String>()
b = mutableListOf<String>()

isListsHasSameContent = a sameContentWith b
```

Comment: Awesome. This should be the accepted answer for collection (if not using array)

Comment: Watch out for edge condition; `listOf("a", "b", "b").sameContentWith(listOf("a", "a", "b"))` is true when it might be expected to return false.

Comment: @dnault thanks for mentioning this. well, looks like this works perfectly for Sets :)

Comment: `sameContentWith` unfortunately has even more errors. You can give elements into the left collection that aren't in the right collection, and even then `sameContentWith` might return true - for example in this case: `listOf("a", "b").sameContentWith(listOf("a", "a"))`

Answer (score 5):

For a simple equals (not deep equals!):

```
otherArray.size == array.size && otherArray.filter { !array.contains(it) }.isEmpty()
```

This code will compare the size and the items. The items are compared with `.equals()`.

Comment: This does not account for the order of the Array; however the general method is good for Sets.

Answer (score 2):

In koltin if your array or ArrayList is type of a **data** `Class` you can simply compare *array :a* and *array :b*

like this

`if(a == b)`

it will return simple boolean if it matched all the value of both arrays, but if you are matching other-than data **data** `Class` then you can use this extension to compare it with single value

```
fun <T> Array<T>.isEqual(comparable: Array<T>): Boolean {
    var isChanged = true

    if (this.size == comparable.size) {
        for (index in 0 until comparable.size) {
            if (this[index] != comparable[index]) {
                isChanged = false
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        isChanged = false
    }

    return isChanged
}
```

then you can use your array

```
    val a = arrayOf("first", "second")
    val b = arrayOf("first", "second")

    println(a.isEqual(b)) //true

    a[0] = "third"

    println(a.isEqual(b)) //false
```

Comment: Where do you save this function for future reuse? Github repo?

Answer (score 0):

### Checking of Two ArrayList equality:

```
fun isArrayListEquals(
    list1: ArrayList<CustomItem>,
    list2: ArrayList<CustomItem>,
): Boolean {
    if (list1.size != list2.size) return false

    val hash1 = list1.map { it.hashCode() }.toSet()
    val hash2 = list2.map { it.hashCode() }.toSet()

    return (hash1.intersect(hash2)).size == hash1.size
}


import java.util.Objects;

public class CustomItem {
    private String id, title, key;

    // implement getter/setter here

    // Mandatory
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, title, key);
    }
}
```

### Or Simple Solution:

```
fun isArrayListEquals(
    list1: ArrayList<CustomItem>,
    list2: ArrayList<CustomItem>,
): Boolean {
    val gson = Gson()
    val list1Str = gson.toJson(list1)
    val list2Str = gson.toJson(list2)
    return list1Str == list2Str
}
```