# GSON throwing Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: kotlin, gson

Facing this problem past few days.Does any guys check this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.How can I solved this problem?

> GSON throwing Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Problem coming from

```
 override fun onSuccess(str_SUCCESS: String)
    {
        System.out.println("JSON_IS"+str_SUCCESS)

       val paymentScheduleModel = Gson().fromJson<PaymentScheduleModel>(str_SUCCESS, PaymentScheduleModel::class.java) // Problem here

    }
```

**Json Response is**

```
{
  "status": {
    "statusCode": 10016,
    "isSuccess": true,
    "message": "Success"
  },
  "data": {
    "payback_schedule": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "paid_amount": "INR NaN",
        "paidStatus": "Upcoming Payback",
        "paid_status": "P",
        "s_date": "05/01/2018 12:31:10",
        "e_date": "11/01/2018 12:31:10",
        "current_balance": "INR 399",
        "payanytime_button_status": "active",
        "btnColor": "red",
        "btnHexColor": "#D2322D"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "paid_amount": "INR NaN",
        "paidStatus": "Upcoming Payback",
        "paid_status": "P",
        "s_date": "12/01/2018 12:31:10",
        "e_date": "18/01/2018 12:31:10",
        "current_balance": "INR 399",
        "payanytime_button_status": "active",
        "btnColor": "red",
        "btnHexColor": "#D2322D"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**PaymentScheduleModel**

```
data class PaymentScheduleModel(@SerializedName("payback_schedule") val payback_schedule: PaymentSchedule)

data class PaymentSchedule

                      (@SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
                       @SerializedName("paid_amount") val paid_amount:String,
                       @SerializedName("paidStatus") val paidStatus:String,
                       @SerializedName("paid_status") val paid_status:String,
                       @SerializedName("s_date") val s_date:String,
                       @SerializedName("e_date") val e_date:String,
                       @SerializedName("current_balance") val current_balance:String,
                       @SerializedName("payanytime_button_status") val payanytime_button_status:String,
                       @SerializedName("btnColor") val btnColor:String,
                       @SerializedName("btnHexColor") val btnHexColor:String)
```

Comment: Hello @Kankana, your model class does not looks proper. Use gson converter or pojo generator for create model class.

Comment: Look at your JSON `payback_schedule` is an array not an object. It will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45605731/4693278

Answer (score 0):

Your model object does not match your Json.

You are trying to parse a JsonObject `PaymentScheduleModel` which has sub object "payback_schedule" of type `PaymentSchedule` but you have a JsonObject which has a sub object "data" which is what has the sub object "payback_schedule". So really, you want to parse the "data" block.

You have two options:

1: Create another model that wraps the data block and parse that:

```
data class PaymentScheduleData(@SerializedName("data") val payback_schedule_model: PaymentScheduleModel)

override fun onSuccess(str_SUCCESS: String) {
    val paymentScheduleData = Gson().fromJson<PaymentScheduleData>(str_SUCCESS, PaymentScheduleData::class.java)
    // Now use paymentScheduleData.payback_schedule_model
}
```

2: Pull out the data portion first, then parse:

```
override fun onSuccess(str_SUCCESS: String) {
    // Get the root JsonObject
    val jsonObject = Gson().fromJson<JsonObject>(str_SUCCESS, JsonObject::class.java)

    // Get the "data" block that matches the model and parse that
    val paymentScheduleModel = Gson().fromJson<PaymentScheduleModel>(jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("data"), PaymentScheduleModel::class.java)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `payback_schedule` is holding an array instead of object. So, `payback_schedule` should be `Array<PaymentSchedule>` instead of `PaymentSchedule`.

```
data class PaymentScheduleModel(@SerializedName("payback_schedule") val payback_schedule: Array<PaymentSchedule>)
```

PS. You are suggested to implement your own `equals()` and `hashCode()` function if your data class contains `Array` because the default implementation of `Array`'s `equals()` function compares the [referential equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#referential-equality). Suggested reading: [Equals method for data class in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524422/equals-method-for-data-class-in-kotlin)