# How to hash data class with array property

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have `data class ItemMainData(val title: String?, val fields: Array<Field>)`. What's the proper way to override `hashCode()`?

I am aware of this answer ([Equals method for data class in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524422/equals-method-for-data-class-in-kotlin)), but in that case the hash of the array is sufficient to be the hash of the data class. It's not so in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press "Generate" in the IDE and select "equals() and hashCode()" from the menu, it will generate the correct implementation for you. The implementation will use the `Arrays.hashCode()` method to generate the hash code of the array.