# Kotlin, how to test (int)array

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

I'd like to find a nice and concise way to test intarray

at first I tried

`mFaces[0].mIndices shouldBe intArrayOf(0, 1, 2)`

where `mIndices` is

`var mIndices: IntArray = IntArray(0)`

but fails. Intellij also suggests me to override `equals()` with `Array`s

Then I wanted to try something like this

`mFaces[0].mIndices.all { it. == index } shouldBe true`

but it looks like there is no way to retrieve the index of `it` inside `all{..}` or is this

```
var p = 0
mFaces[0].mIndices.all { it == p++ } shouldBe true
```

the only possibility?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `mIndices` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35272761/3255152

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java (Kotlin) arrays are compared by reference, **not** by content. That means that `intArrayOf(1, 2, 3) != intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)`.

To compare content of arrays you have 2 options:

1. Use deep comparison:

   `Arrays.deepequals(mFaces[0].mIndices, intArrayOf(0, 1, 2))`
2. Use lists:

   `mFaces[0].mIndices.toList() == listOf(0, 1, 2)`

Comment: Strictly speaking, the equals operator calls the method `equals()` (this is Kotlin so far) which in the case of arrays happens to be implemented as a reference comparison (this is Java's fault).

Comment: What about `mFaces[0].mIndices.toList().contentEquals(listOf(0, 1, 2))`?